# Exclude module code from the deployment JAR as a build option

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

Just wanted to clarify whether it's possible to exclude complete module code in the deployment JAR in a maven spring-boot project `>mvn clean install`.

E.g I have a project with below structure and just wanted to  `module-2`  code in the deployment jar when I build the project as a option. That means if I wanted to have the code in the jar even that should be possible.

```
├───module-1
|
├───module-2
|
├───module-3
```

Comment: So you don't want to include module-2 on the jar that you generate?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, but only thing is NOT always. Basically I wanted to place the test common code in that `module-2 ` which can be access from other project, but shouldn't be part of production deployment.

Comment: Ah. The way I've usually seen that done is to put your test common code into its own library and include it as a test dependency. I've never seen it done with modules like this.

Comment: As mentioned by @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas put the common code into module src/main/java and add it as a dependency with scope test..

Comment: @khmarbaise Just to clarify, as both of you explained, then that `module-2 ` code can be accessed by outside from another repo, however when deploy (I mean production deployment for instance)  the main project code (e.g. the one mentioned in the question), that `module-2 ` code will be excluded. Is that correct?

Comment: Test dependencies are not included in your production jar/war.

Comment: If you define a dependency with `<scope>test</scope>` it will not made being part of war/ear etc. The `jar` does not even contain any dependency